# mysql data insert into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two sql queries:

```
$query0=mysql_query("SELECT caseNumber FROM shipped_data WHERE palette='P0' AND shipInvoiceNumber='2011/229'");
$query1=mysql_query("SELECT caseNumber FROM shipped_data WHERE palette='P1' AND shipInvoiceNumber='2011/229'");
```

and using following php script to fetch data,

```
while($res0=mysql_fetch_array($query0))
{
    $r0=$res0['caseNumber'];
    $q0=mysql_query("INSERT INTO pallet  (P00) VALUES ('$r0')")or die("Error");
}
while($res1=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
    print  $r1=$res1['caseNumber'];
    $q1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO pallet  (P01) VALUES ('$r1')")or die("Error");
}
```

This is the result:

First query inserts rows 1-10 of the data for coloumn1
The second query inserts rows 11-20 of the data for coloumn2.

What I need is rows 1-10 to be also inserted in column2, instead of rows 11-20

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Please, give us state of your table before insert queries and after insert.

Comment: this is my output http://oi54.tinypic.com/35cr4tz.jpg .... and i want to do like this : http://oi55.tinypic.com/ajmcuf.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might help you looking at your problem from a different point of view. You can also perform your needs without having to loop through the records. You can execute the following SQL queries with PHP, or - if you have the ability - put this in a Stored Procedure, and call that.

The following SQL does the same as your PHP script.

```
INSERT INTO pallet (P00) 
    SELECT caseNumber 
    FROM shipped_data 
    WHERE palette='P0' 
        AND shipInvoiceNumber='2011/229';

INSERT INTO pallet (P01) 
    SELECT caseNumber 
    FROM shipped_data 
    WHERE palette='P1' 
        AND shipInvoiceNumber='2011/229';
```

Comment: this is my output http://oi54.tinypic.com/35cr4tz.jpg .... and i want to do like this : http://oi55.tinypic.com/ajmcuf.jpg

Comment: this is my output http://oi54.tinypic.com/35cr4tz.jpg .... and i want to do like this : http://oi55.tinypic.com/ajmcuf.jpg

Comment: I'm sorry, but I believe you have something wrong in your table setup. May I ask you what the purpose is? Maybe I can help you coming up with a better solution than your current one, because frankly that doesn't look good.